# Select the correct html element with rvest

Tags: web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

Im some ocassion a Stack user help me for make this script. Im edit it for add more attributes but I have problems when try to add **Authors**

The Author label is next to `target` and `href`. I have problem in this part.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(rvest)

 startTime <- Sys.time()
 get_cg <- function(pages) {

   cat("Scraping page", pages, "\n")

   page <-
   str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover? 
   scope=10568%2F106146&query=cassava&submit=&rpp=10&page=", pages) %>%
   read_html()


  tibble(
  title = page %>%
  html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
  html_element(".description-info") %>%
  html_text2(), # run well

  fecha = page %>% 
  html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
  html_element(".date") %>%
  html_text2(), # run well

  Type = page %>% 
  html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
  html_element(".artifact-type") %>%
  html_text2(), # run well

  Autor= page %>% 
  html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>% 
  html_element(".description-info") %>%
  html_attr("href"), # not download the Authors

  link = page %>%
  html_elements(".ds-artifact-item") %>%
  html_element(".description-info") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% # run well
  str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org", .)
  )
     }

  df <- map_dfr(1, get_cg)

  endTime <- Sys.time()
  print(endTime - startTim)
```

Im try with other selector but get NA

Comment: Most articles there has more than one author, i.e. there are 10 articles per page but on 1st page alone there are 80 authors. For your current approach element numbers must match, are you looking for a ways to change that logic or do you want to collect just one author (perhaps the 1st) for every book?

Comment: The idea is to obtain a data frame with this information per book. Extract all the information. So it is important to get all the authors for each book. Then I could extract each author separately with regular expressions

Comment: Amazing code, more short.  Im check the Author names and is very confuse.  Is possible obtain this column but only the names?
Im avoid collapse but dont run.

Comment: From your example code it seemed that you were after links ( `Autor = ... html_attr("href")` ) , I updated the answer to include just names.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you a collapsed list of authors for each book, separated by `;` , basically the same as presented on the page:

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts = F)

startTime <- Sys.time()
get_cg <- function(pages) {
  
  cat("Scraping page", pages, "\n")
  
  page <-
    str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org/discover?scope=10568%2F106146&query=cassava&submit=&rpp=10&page=", pages) %>%
    read_html()
  
  html_elements(page, "div.artifact-description > div.artifact-description")  %>% 
    map_df(~ list(
      title = html_element(.x, ".description-info") %>% html_text2(),
      fecha = html_element(.x, ".date") %>% html_text2(),
      Type  = html_element(.x, ".artifact-type") %>% html_text2(),
      # Autor_links = html_elements(.x,".description-info > span  > a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste(collapse = ";"),
      Autor = html_element(.x, "span.description-info") %>% html_text2(),
      link  = html_element(.x, "a.description-info") %>% html_attr("href") %>% str_c("https://cgspace.cgiar.org", .)
    )) 
}

df <- map_dfr(1, get_cg)
#> Scraping page 1

endTime <- Sys.time()
print(endTime - startTime)
#> Time difference of 0.989037 secs
```

Result:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>    title                                                 fecha Type  Autor link 
#>    <chr>                                                 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Global Climate Regions for Cassava                    2020… Type… Hyma… http…
#>  2 Performance of the CSM–MANIHOT–Cassava model for sim… 2021… Type… Phon… http…
#>  3 Adoption of cassava improved modern varieties in the… 2020  Type… Laba… http…
#>  4 First report of Sri Lankan cassava mosaic virus and … 2021… Type… Chit… http…
#>  5 Surveillance and diagnostics dataset on Sri Lankan c… 2020  Type… Siri… http…
#>  6 Socieconomic and soil conservation practices for cas… 2022… Type… Ibar… http…
#>  7 The transformation and outcome of traditional cassav… 2020  Type… Dou,… http…
#>  8 Cassava Annual Report 2019                            2020  Type… Inte… http…
#>  9 Cassava Annual Report 2020                            2021… Type… Bece… http…
#> 10 Adoption of cassava improved modern varieties in the… 2020  Type… Flor… http…

glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 10
#> Columns: 5
#> $ title <chr> "Global Climate Regions for Cassava", "Performance of the CSM–MA…
#> $ fecha <chr> "2020-08-03", "2021-05-01", "2020", "2021-04-23", "2020", "2022-…
#> $ Type  <chr> "Type:Dataset", "Type:Journal Article", "Type:Dataset", "Type:Jo…
#> $ Autor <chr> "Hyman, Glenn G.", "Phoncharoen, Phanupong; Banterng, Poramate; …
#> $ link  <chr> "https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/109500", "https://cgspac…
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is excellent this update. Run very well. I'm goin to scrape all site. Tnks! The `Autor` was very difficult for me because I'm not expert in html, try with xpaht but dont work well.